# Is there any element / advice on using websockets with Polymer?

Tags: websocket, polymer

Absolute beginner to Polymer. Is there any Element / helper etc. to use? I found http://hph.is/web-socket/ do I need more? I using websockets in Polymer any "special"? To be honest, I found it "interesting" that there is no documentation on websockets in Polymer in the official release, which makes we wonder if

- Websockets in Polymer are so straightforward that they do not deserve any special attention;
- Wwbsockets is not the way to go according to the Polymer authors.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the reason why they're not well documented together is because the implementation is pretty simple. Create a `my-websocket` element and initialise the underlying `WebSocket` in the element's `ready` function. Then you can fire events (`this.fire(...)`) from each of the underlying websocket's listeners (`onopen`, `onerror`, `onmessage`, `onclose`) which will allow you to bind through the element:

```
<my-websocket on-message="{{_onMessage}}"></my-websocket>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use polymer's firebase-collection element which uses websockets under the hood.